# Cannot bind the parameter "Path" to the argument, since it is NULL

Tags: powershell

I have been trying to write a PowerShell script for syncing folders and have used the guide [*"How to Sync Folders With PowerShell"*](https://www.business.com/articles/powershell-sync-folders/). Unfortunately I am getting an error. Is it possible that the guide is deprecated?

```
$Folder1Path = 'C:\Users\Name\OneDrive'
$Folder2Path = 'C:\Users\Name\Documents\Folder'

$Folder1Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder1Path
$Folder2Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder2Path

$FileDiffs = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Folder1Files -DifferenceObject $Folder2Files

$FilesDiffs | foreach {
    $copyParams = @{
        'Path' = $_.InputObject.FullName
    }

    if ($_.SideIndicator -eq '<=') {
        $copyParams.Destination = $Folder2Path
    } else {
        $copyParams.Destination = $Folder1Path
    }
    Copy-Item @copyParams
}
```

Error message:

```
Copy-Item: Cannot bind the parameter "Path" to the argument, since it is NULL.
In C:\Users\Name\Documents\PowerShell Scripts\Script.ps1:21 symbol:12
+     Copy-Item @copyParams
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Comment: You're not validating whether you're getting a return from `$FilesDiffs`.  The `InputObject.FullName` property doesn't exist, so you're getting `$null`.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: If `Compare-Object` produces no output, `$FilesDiffs` receives `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value` (in most contexts, this is the same as `$null`), and that by definition doesn't send anything through the pipeline, so the `foreach[-object]` block would never execute.

Comment: @neolith: The symptom is not consistent with your code, which looks correct. Is there something else going on that your sample code is not showing?

Comment: I don't really understand foreach loop very well. I am assuming the line with `'Path' = $_InputObject.FullName` creates a path out of the filename and this doesn't work.

Comment: @mklement0: The first folder is a OneDrive folder synced to my pc and the second folder one that I created. Maybe the error is related to the first one being a synced folder??

Comment: @neolith: The error message implies that the argument value is `$null`, so its hypothetical content shouldn't come into play. Inspect the content of `$copyParams` before you pass it to `Copy-Item`.

Comment: If you checked/fixed the second line in your actual script, consider also updating your question so the typo doesn't mislead others.

Comment: @Andy: I updated the script. Thank you.

Comment: @mklement0: The only thing that can be NULL is the content of Folder 2, since it is empty. I actually only want to copy files from Folder 1 to Folder 2. I think this script checks which folder is missing files and copying them in both directions, isn't it?

Comment: @neolith: If the content of folder 2 is null, the `Compare-Object` call would fail. Does it? Execution by default continues, so the `foreach` (`ForEach-Object`) script block would still be entered, in which case the `Path` entry of the hashtable used for splatting would be `$null`, causing `Copy-Item` to fail. Yes, the code copies in both directions. To copy just to folder 2, remove the `else` branch and move the `Copy-Item` call into the `if` branch.